# How to set all selected vertices to height of another vertex?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, vertices

Let's say i have selected all these vertices which you can see in this screenshot, and i want to set the height to the same height as the marked vertex (see red arrow in screenshot)

[image]

I always copy the height from the target vertex, then i select each vertex one by one and paste the height into it.  But this takes a very long time, especially if you have big models. Is there an easier way to do this?

Result should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the pivot point for transforms to be the active element, by choosing *Active Element* for the *Pivot Point* in the bar below the *3D View*:

[image]

If you have *Pie Menus* enabled, you can press <kbd>.</kbd>><kbd>7</kbd> instead.

Then select all the vertices you want to affect making sure that the one whose height you want to copy is the *active* one (i.e. select it last) and just *Scale* in the *Z axis direction* to *0*, by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to scale to 0, i want all my selected vertices to be the same height as my target vertice. If i do it like you describe, then the position of all my vertices is changed and i have to adjust everything again.

Comment: Try it first. You can undo (Ctrl Z) if this is not what you want

Comment: Still worked in blender 3.6.2

Answer (score 2):

Open the properties shelf (<kbd>N</kbd> key), select the vertex with the desired height, place the cursor over the "z" box in the transform panel of the tool shelf, and copy (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd>) the value in that box. Then select all of the vertices you want to be the same height as the original vertex, and scale (<kbd>S</kbd> key) them constraining the movement to the z axis by pressing the <kbd>Z</kbd> key, and setting the scale factor to zero. Then, without deselecting the vertices, move the cursor over the "z" box in the transform panel of the properties shelf, and paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd>) the Z value. This applies the height characteristic of the original vertex to all of those selected.